# Drag And Drop html control over a canvas image using Angular Js

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, jquery-ui-draggable

I want an Application where a user can drag and drop HTML control like textbox, checkbox, calendar over an image and the user can also able to resize it. I have done so many R&D but didn't find any solution. I am attaching the image below for reference.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: What is "pdf canvas image"?

Comment: pdf  canvas is a image take any image but the control should be the drag over an image

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: I want it on Angular Js